# Weird error when importing module

Tags: c, d, dmd

**This is my main file** (the one triggering the error) :

```
/**********************************************************
 **
 ** LOGRAMM
 ** Interpreter
 ** 
 ** (c) 2009-2014, Dr.Kameleon
 **
 **********************************************************
 ** expression.d
 **********************************************************/

module expression;

//================================================
// Imports
//================================================

import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

import components.argument;

//================================================
// C Interface for Bison
//================================================

extern (C) 
{
    void* Expression_new(Expression l, char* op, Expression r) { return cast(void*)(new Expression(l,to!string(op),r)); }
    void* Expression_newFromArgument(Argument a) { return cast(void*)(new Expression(a)); }
}

//================================================
// Functions
//================================================

class Expression
{
    Expression left;
    string operator;
    Expression right;

    Argument arg;

    this(Expression l, string op, Expression r)
    {
        left = l;
        operator = op;
        right = r;

        arg = null;
    }

    this(Argument a)
    {
        arg = a;
    }

    void print()
    {
        writeln("Expression: ");
        if (!arg)
        {
            writeln("\t | Operator: " ~ operator ~ ", Left: ");
            left.print();
            writeln("Right: ");
            right.print();
        }
        else
        {
            writeln("\t | Argument: ");
            arg.print();
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is the error I'm getting** (*there are like 20 different modules, and it's the first time I'm getting this type of error*) :

```
components/expression.d(21): Error: module argument from file components/argument.d must be imported as module 'argument'
```

(21 is the `import...` line at the beginning)

Any idea what's going on here?

---

**P.S.**

- I've been coding for almost 15 hours in a row, so I suppose it could be something *really* obvious that I'm not able to spot...
- I've also tried `import argument;` - but this wouldn't make much difference anyway, since the `argument.d` file *is* in the `components` package, pretty much like any other file that I'm importing in other places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing the module via `import argument;`. Alternatively, open the `argument.d` module and add or change its module declaration to be: `module components.argument;`.

Comment: Well, the `import argument;` idea did *not* work. But the last one, worked beautifully! Thanks a lot! You've saved me so much time!! :-)

Comment: Yeah, the rule should be if a file is EVER imported anywhere, make sure it contains an explicit `module name.here;` at the top of it, every time, cuz eventually this kind of thing will bite you.